# Dart version is 2.2.0 but I get an error requiring version >=2.2.0

Tags: dart, flutter

I have the latest version of Flutter and I'm trying to run the official Flutter gallery app. When I do `dart --version` I get

```
Dart VM version: 2.2.0 (Tue Feb 26 15:04:32 2019 +0100) on "macos_x64"
```

However, when I try to get the packages:

```
[flutter_gallery] flutter packages get
Running "flutter packages get" in flutter_gallery...            
The current Dart SDK version is 2.1.2-dev.0.0.flutter-0a7dcf17eb.

Because flutter_gallery requires SDK version >=2.2.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1)
exit code 1
```

What's interesting is when I run `flutter upgrade` it lists an older version of Dart (Tools).

```
Upgrading Flutter from /Users/leejohnson/dev/flutter...
From https://github.com/flutter/flutter
   a1bee54fd..59ce7d6bf  dev        -> origin/dev
   55a2ee588..f8f2b043e  master     -> origin/master
 * [new tag]             v1.3.13    -> v1.3.13
Already up to date.

Upgrading engine...
Already up-to-date.

Flutter 1.2.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 8661d8aecd (5 weeks ago) • 2019-02-14 19:19:53 -0800
Engine • revision 3757390fa4
Tools • Dart 2.1.2 (build 2.1.2-dev.0.0 0a7dcf17eb)
```

If I understand this error correctly, Flutter is not using the latest version of Dart yet the official Flutter example app requires it. How do I fix this?

Comment: The output of `dart --version` is completely irrelevant for Flutter. What you need to check is `flutter doctor -v` or `flutter --version`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The output of `dart --version` is completely irrelevant for Flutter. What you need to check is `flutter doctor -v` or `flutter --version`. In your case it shows `Tools • Dart 2.1.2 (build 2.1.2-dev.0.0 0a7dcf17eb)`

You probably need to switch to another channel until the next stable channel update

```
flutter channel dev
```

or

```
flutter channel master
```

Comment: The other channels are also broken (severely). What do we do then?

Comment: I'd suggest you create a new question with full information about your system, versions, error messages.

Answer (score 3):

Flutter has its own dart-sdk in `flutter/bin/cache/`. So when you do `dart --version` , its probably another dart sdk in your system.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else stuck (The other channels were broken), what I found was switching to stable then switching versions within stable fixed it for me. You can do this by doing the following:

`flutter versions`

`flutter versions 1.5.5` (Or some other version)