# Checking dart sdk version

Tags: flutter, dart

I just run the flutter command `flutter upgrade` in my project. And after that I am facing this error all the time.

[image]

Comment: It seems that this question might help you: [Dart version is 2.2.0 but I get an error requiring version >=2.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55247424/dart-version-is-2-2-0-but-i-get-an-error-requiring-version-2-2-0)

Answer (score 12):

You can check dart version using:

```
dart --version
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Try this  command in your teminal

`dart --version

`

Answer (score 0):

you can go to your flutter root directory/bin/cache/dart-sdk and click on version file